# jquery mobile either text or icon showing not both

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i am instantiating a button widget like so

```
var button = $('<div>')
 .buttonMarkup({
 icon: 'plus',
 corners: false,
 type: 'button',
})
 .attr('id', 'my-button')
 .text('start') //when this is added the icon vanishes
 .appendTo('#my-div');
```

the trouble is the when i add text no icon is shown. when i add no text icon is shown

is there anything i overlook

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enhance the markup of the div using `.button()`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WcgHa/)**

```
var button = $('<div>')
.buttonMarkup({
  icon: 'plus',
  corners: false,
  type: 'button',
})
 .attr('id', 'my-button')
 .text('start') //when this is added the icon vanishes
 .appendTo('#my-div').button();
```

Comment: thanks a lot omar. i already had the feeling that i missed something substantial.